# Get insert id of the current INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using MySQL and I know in PHP/MySQL I can use [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) (mysqli_insert_id)

But is it possible to do something like this?

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value1, value2, THIS_INSERT_ID)
```

It's for something bigger than this, but hopefully this explains it.

So this gets the same insert id used in that transaction and effectively the id is the same as the 3rd field inserted.

I can't find how to do this anywhere so maybe it's not possible, but wanted confirmation before I look for another solution.

Comment: You would need to put the return ID into a variable ($id) then do an UPDATE table SET col3 = $id WHERE id=$id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The insert ID is only available after the row itself has been inserted.

To achieve what you want, you can run an update immediately afterwards using the insert id, but I can't imagine why you'd want to duplicate the data anyways.

Comment: To answer your question. I am creating a login page where the user is able to create a guest account. Since the username should be unique I like to insert it with "guest + ID". If that already exists (in case a user manually enters guestXXXX) I would append something to it.

In this case I need to generate a random string for the username and insert. Then retrieve the last insert and try the guest name. If that fails try to append and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it's not possible. You don't know the inserted id until you, well, `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you want to do this - and it doesn't make much sense either.

In your table, add a primary key, `id`, and `AUTO_INCREMENT` it. Then, you can query against that `id` column.